# JAX-WS :: unknown extensibility element or attribute "ns1" (in namespace "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")

Tags: java, jax-ws, wsimport

I am using the `wsimport` Ant task:

```
<target name="wsimport">
    <wsimport
        verbose    = "true"
        destdir    ="${javasource-auto-wsimport.dir}"
        package    ="${wsimport-package.name}"
        xnocompile ="true"
        wsdl       ="${wsdl.file}"
    />
</target>
```

and get the following warning:

```
[wsimport] Consider using <depends>/<produces> so that wsimport won't do unnecessary compilation
[wsimport] JAX-WS RI 2.2.8
[wsimport] command line: wsimport -d /playground/jax-ws/client/src-auto-wsimport -Xnocompile -verbose wsdl-auto/MyService.wsdl -p foo.client
[wsimport] parsing WSDL...
[wsimport] 
[wsimport] 
[wsimport] [WARNING] unknown extensibility element or attribute "ns1" (in namespace "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")
[wsimport]   line 17 of file:/playground/jax-ws/client/wsdl-auto/IHello.wsdl
[wsimport] 
[wsimport] [WARNING] unknown extensibility element or attribute "ns2" (in namespace "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")
[wsimport]   line 18 of file:/playground/jax-ws/client/wsdl-auto/IHello.wsdl
[wsimport]
```

Now, the `<depends>/<produces>` stuff I know how to handle - it's the two warnings I worry about. The lines it complains about (line 17 and 18 of the IHello.wsdl file), are:

```
  <input ns1:Action="http://zar.bar.foo/IHello/sayHelloRequest" message="tns:sayHello" xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"/>
  <output ns2:Action="http://zar.bar.foo/IHello/sayHelloResponse" message="tns:sayHelloResponse" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"/>
```

It appears that the tool fails to recognize that `ns1` and `ns2` are properly declared namespace prefixes.

When I invoke the `wsimport` tool from the command line I don't get any warnings whatsoever:

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/wsimport -version
JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01
$/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/wsimport -d src-auto-wsimport/ -p foo.client  -Xnocompile wsdl-auto/MyService.wsdl
parsing WSDL...



Generating code...
```

My questions are:

1. why the discrepancy?
2. given the discrepancy, should I be using the command-line version of the `wsimport` tool or the Ant-task based one?
3. why do I get these warnings?

Comment: Where you able to resolve the issue? I have the same problem/issue.

Comment: No, in the end I gave up on `wsimport` and implemented my own SOAP/WSDL code generation.

Comment: That's a pity. I guess I will implement a minimal testcase and will file a bug with JAX-WS.

Comment: Funny thing is, I see these errors when calling wsimport from Java 8 - using Java 7 does not show them ... ?!?